# wxpython: How to influence wx objects from another wx object's callback function?

Tags: python, events, callback, wxpython, handler

I'm coding a small GUI at the moment and wanted to know how I could influence wxpython widgets' states from within another's callback function.

At the moment, I can't influence widgets from my callback functions because in the callback function my button widgets are not going to be defined.

For example, one thing I want to do is upon *btnLoad* being pressed, *btnSave* should become enabled (see below).

```
    btnSave = wx.Button(...)
    btnSave.Disable()

    btnLoad = wx.Button(...)

    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onBtnLoad, btnLoad)

def onBtnLoad(self, event):
    btnSolve.Enable()    # this is where I have issues. Obviously because btnSolve is undefined here.
```

Thanks in advance :)

P.S. Apologies if I've said something odd, it's my second day coding user interfaces and wxpython.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
import wx

class ButtonFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, value):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,None)
        self.btn1 = wx.Button(self, -1, ("Clickable"))
        self.btn2 = wx.Button(self, -1, ("Not Clickable"))
        self.btnSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.btnSizer.Add(self.btn1 , 0, wx.RIGHT, 10)
        self.btnSizer.Add(self.btn2 , 0, wx.RIGHT, 10)
        self.btn1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnPressA)
        self.btn2.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnPressB)
        self.btn2.Disable()
        self.SetSizer(self.btnSizer)
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

    def OnPressA(self,evt):
        self.btn1.SetLabel('Not Clickable')
        self.btn2.SetLabel('Clickable')
        self.btn2.Enable()
        self.btn1.Disable()
        self.Layout()

    def OnPressB(self,evt):
        self.btn2.SetLabel('Not Clickable')
        self.btn1.SetLabel('Clickable')
        self.btn1.Enable()
        self.btn2.Disable()
        self.Layout()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    ButtonFrame(None)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Not knowing how experienced you are in these matters, you might find this description of the variable `self` useful.
https://pythontips.com/2013/08/07/the-self-variable-in-python-explained/

Comment: Oh this works perfectly! Thanks so much :D
I've noticed `self` is a bit different in Python but now I know why.